# Java - Get XML Element based on value of another element

Tags: java, xml, xslt

So I have an XML file that has the below format

```
 <Document DocID="doc1" DocType="Message" MimeType="message">
        <Tags>
                <Tag TagName="#From" TagDataType="Text" TagValue="Jim"/>
                <Tag TagName="#To" TagDataType="Text" TagValue="hello@so.com
                <Tag TagName="#Subject" TagDataType="Text" TagValue="This Subject"/>

        </Tags>
        <Files>
                <File FileType="Text">
                        <ExternalFile FilePath="text_000" FileName="hello.txt"/>
                </File>
        </Files>
        <Locations>
                <Location>
                        <LocationURI>allen-p\&apos;Sent Mail</LocationURI>
                </Location>
        </Locations>
</Document>
```

I want to focus more on the tags:

```
<Tag TagName="#TO" TagDataType="Text" TagValue="Jim"/>
```

Say I want to find ALL of the Tags that have a `TagName "#TO"` and I want to get its corresponding `TagValue` (In this case it would be "Jim").

I need to do that for every tag where `TagName="#TO"`. and get the `TagValue`.

How could I do this in Java?

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: Can you provide me with a sample code wherein I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use DOM to parse an XML Document you could try this :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> toTags = parseTags("#To");
    toTags.forEach(tag -> System.out.println(tag));
}

public static List<String> parseTags(String tag){
    List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();

    Document doc = getXmlDocument("src/test/Document.xml");
    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();

    NodeList tagNode = root.getElementsByTagName("Tag");

    for(int i = 0; i < tagNode.getLength(); i++){
        Node n = tagNode.item(i);

        NamedNodeMap attributes = n.getAttributes();
        attributes.getLength();
        Node tagName = attributes.getNamedItem("TagName");
        if(tagName.getNodeValue().equals(tag)){
            Node tagValue = attributes.getNamedItem("TagValue");
            tags.add(tagValue.getNodeValue());
        }        
    }

    return tags;
}

private static Document getXmlDocument(String path){
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder domBuilder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = domBuilder.parse(new File(path));
        return doc;
    } catch (SAXException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath to get your desired value, check the code below, this will get you the TagValue in TagName="#To"

```
    String query = "/Document//Tags/Tag[contains(@TagName,'To')]/@TagValue";
    String inputXML = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("yourfile.xml"));
    InputSource source = new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(inputXML.getBytes("utf-8")));
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = documentBuilder.parse(source);

    XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

    String toValue = xpath.evaluate(query, document);
    System.out.println(toValue);
```

One more thing, you need to add apache commons-io as dependency to run the above code.